# how to install mcrypt and add mcrypt.h to my C program files?

Tags: c, encryption, header-files, mcrypt

I need to work on trying to get AES encryption/decryption on some examples and have to use mcrypt.h in my C files. However, I do not know how to install them. I have downloaded and unzipped mcrypt-2.6.7-win32 which from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/

I can't seem to figure out how to continue and "install" this header. Please advice.

Comment: FYI, libmcrypt is abandonware (even your link shows that it hasn't been touched in 5 years) and you shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need add those files to your project, add #include mcrypt.h to source which uses mcrypt, and add mcrypt.a to be linked together with your code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you however, please elaborate on how to "add mcrypt.a"?

Comment: It depends on the environment that you are programming in. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Codeblocks

Comment: This links should help you: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/